# Rock paper scissors game how to make it infinite

Tags: python

How can I make it so the game is infinite? and is there a way to simplify this code?

I have tried to work around but can't seem to figure it out.

```
# A rock paper scissors game.
import random

Move1=input("Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit: ").lower()

Move2=["r","p","s"]

while Move1 != "q":
    if Move1 == "r" or "p" or "s" or "q":
        # print(random.choice(Move2))
        Move2=random.choice(Move2)
        if Move1=="r" and Move2=="s":
            print("You've won")
            break
        elif Move2=="p":
            print("You lost!")
            break
        elif Move2=="r":
            print("You went even!")
            break
        if Move1=="p" and Move2=="s":
            print("You lost!")
            break
        elif Move2=="p":
            print("You went even!")
            break
        elif Move2=="r":
            print("You won!")
            break
        if Move1=="s" and Move2=="s":
            print("You went even!")
            break
        elif Move2=="p":
            print("You won!")
            break
        elif Move2=="r":
            print("You lost!")
            break
    else:
        print("You've quit the game!")
        exit()
```

Tried to remove break

Comment: `if Move1 == "r" or "p" or "s" or "q":` is not correct. It should be `if Move1 in ("r", "p", "s", "q"):` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true

Comment: Get rid of all the `break` statements and the loop will be infinite until the user enters `q`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the request for input inside the loop. Use `while True:` around the loop to make it infinite. Remove all the `break` statements after reporting the winners and losers.

Don't use the same variable `Move2` for the list of moves and the computer's move. That will prevent making a computer choice on the 2nd round.

```
# A rock paper scissors game.
import random

allowed_moves=["r","p","s"]

while True:
    player_move=input("Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit: ").lower()
    if player_move in allowed_moves:
        Move2=random.choice(allowed_moves)
        if player_move=="r" and Move2=="s":
            print("You've won")
        elif Move2=="p":
            print("You lost!")
        elif Move2=="r":
            print("You went even!")
        if player_move=="p" and Move2=="s":
            print("You lost!")
        elif Move2=="p":
            print("You went even!")
        elif Move2=="r":
            print("You won!")
        if player_move=="s" and Move2=="s":
            print("You went even!")
        elif Move2=="p":
            print("You won!")
        elif Move2=="r":
            print("You lost!")
    else if player_move == 'q':
        print("You've quit the game!")
        break
    else:
        print("That's not a valid move!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-evaluate the input at the end of the while loop. Or you put it into the while condition. So you could do `while (Move1 := input(...)) != "q"`.

Also your first if check is always true because of the `or "p"`. You would have to do `or Move1 == "p" or Move1 == "s" or Move1 == "q"`

You could simplify it with `if Move1 in {"r", "p", "s", "q"}`

Answer (score 0):

Abstracting some of the game logic to a function is a start in the direction of simplifying.  But there are other ways to simplify.  Here's an example of it along with what I think you mean by making the game infinite.

```
def play(move1, move2):
    # the logic
    print("you win")
    # more logic


is_playing = True
while is_playing:
    Move1 = input(
        "Enter your move: (r)ock (p)aper (s)cissors or (q)uit: ").lower()
    Move2 = ["r", "p", "s"]
    if Move1 == 'q':
        print("You've quit the game!")
        is_playing = False
        break
    play(Move1, Move2)
```

Let me know if that helps or not